# Aliyot for life cycle events

Tags: minhag, torah-service

Why do life cycle events such as becoming a bar mitzvah, getting married, having children, and commemorating deaths of loved ones, as well as others obligate one in recieving an aliyah?

Comment: How do you know that it's obligatory to receive an aliyah? Perhaps it's just a custom, as a way of honoring someone. If you could provide some backup for your statement that they're obligated, that would be invaluable.

Comment: Ive seen people not get aliyot in these cases. Seemingly they dont have an obligation.

Comment: Its the biur halacha in siman קלו who mentions it

Comment: I think you need to provide some better context for your assumption. Shulchan Aruch mentions that it is customary to give aliyah preference to people celebrating SOME of the events you cited such as the sandak, mohel, upcoming chattan. I am unaware that there is any mention of aliyah for a Bar Mitzvah, contrary to common custom that seems to imply that every Bar Mitzvah MUST receive an aliyah.